# Wrong portlet version and deploy problems with Maven

Tags: maven, liferay, liferay-6

I created a new portlet plugin (build based on Maven) by using Liferay IDE.

If I launch a `mvn liferay:deploy`, deploy process ends successfully. But if run the same process (deploy) another time, the deploy fails.

```
Updating my-portlet from version 6.2.5 to version 0.1
Not updating my-portlet because version 6.2.5 is newer than version 0.1
```

I declared `<version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>` in my `pom.xml` file, but Liferay tells me (also in control panel) that plugin installed version is 6.2.5.

I'm using Liferay CE 6.2 (ga6), and following settings:

```
<liferay.version>6.2.5</liferay.version>
<liferay.maven.plugin.version>6.2.5</liferay.maven.plugin.version>
```

That are used (excluding portal dependecies) only in the following lines:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.liferay.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>liferay-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${liferay.maven.plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>...</executions>
            <configuration>
                <liferayVersion>${liferay.version}</liferayVersion>
                ...
```

Do you have any idea about my problem?

Thank you.

**EDIT**
The problem is the same (portlet version 6.2.5) also by setting liferay.version and/or liferay.maven.plugin.version to 6.2.4...

Comment: Have you changed finalName of your project? What is the name of war?

Comment: Can you please post the content of 'liferay-plugin-package.properties' file here?

Comment: Many thanks to everyone. I solved just by renaming the final WAR (I suppose the problem was due to some dashes in the file name)... I'm going to write a complete answer to this question in order to help future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

and thanks for comments and reply.

I think I found a solution, and I would like to share it for future readers... because I didn't find it on the web... or better, it is on the web, but isn't related to this issue.

My original (Maven) module name was (due to project original specifications): `client-external-customer-portlet`, so resulting WAR was `client-external-customer-portlet-0.1-SNAPSHOT.war`
[Someone on the web](http://xcafebabe.blogspot.it/2013/07/liferay-error-requested-resource-my.html) suggested to remove dashes from portlet name `-` in order to avoid a well-known Spring-mvc-portlet error.
I resolved my issue just applying the same suggestion to my portlet name: now it is `clientExternalCustomerPortlet` and resulting WAR is `clientExternalCustomerPortlet-0.1-SNAPSHOT.war`. In this way everything works fine.

My 5 cents are that LR deploy system uses dashes as special separators also in the deploy process.

By the way I get this idea when, deploying `client-external-theme-0.1-SNAPSHOT.war`, logs said that the context name was only `client-ext`.

I hope it can be useful.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that liferay starts with version 6.2.5 in your case, and you are trying to deploy a 0.1 version that is older than by default on Liferay.

I would try to deploy the portlet without version, just delete from name-portlet forward.

```
Portletname-portlet.war
```

In that case, liferay takes the version 6.2.5 like portlet version and deploy it succesfully.

Comment: Thank you. By the way I think it is not a solution, but just a workaround to skip a security measure of LR deploy system. As I wrote: if I deploy the same WAR (with the same name) twice, then the second time I get the error. The problem is in the original file name (see the answer I'm going to write)